# Combining two text files for seperate column each file in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 5 columns id, site, menu, categ and links. I load data for the second column(site), from a `.txt` file. I tried to load data from another `.txt` file in column menu, but it shows the data of the file, in the rows right after the rows that are filled with data in column site. Is there a way to put the data of the columns in the same rows?

Answer (score 0):

You could load it 2 into temporary tables then combine the results.

1. Start by creating a table called foo with two columns, ID
   (autoincrement) and value (varchar(1000))
2. Load the first text file into foo.
3. Create a second table, bar, with ID and value columns also.
4. Then insert into your final table via

--

```
INSERT INTO foobar (site, column)
SELECT foo.value, bar.value
FROM foo
JOIN bar
 ON foo.id = bar.id;
```